# Taking MySQL dump from another machine

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, linux

I have a MySQL db on Machine A and I want to access the mysqldump from machine B.

Both machines are running on Linux and I also have the credentials of both, but I can't access the mysqldump. What can I try?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In General if you have the credentials for accessing MySql from Machine B.

You should have MySQL user name , host name and Password.Then You can write the Command for taking backup

On Machine B Write

```
mysqldump -h Your_host_name -u user_name -p password --all-databases > backup.sql
```

If You Face issues there may be some network issue try some things as

1. Use ping with ip address to check that DNS isn't broken. eg. ping Machine A
2. Use mysql client to connect from B to A. eg mysql -u user -pPASS --host=Host_Name --port=3306 (substitute whatever port you are connecting to the master on)

Comment: @AbdulManaf - Can this be done if I need to SSH to the server? And what about the situation when I want to initiate a mysqldump and restore from my local machine -> from server A to server B. I have SSH for both the servers. Adding -i /path/to/private/key is not working for me somehow.

Answer (score 3):

This is for taking a dump of a specific table

```
mysqldump -h 'hostname' -vv -u'user' -p'password' database_name table_name | gzip > table_name.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use `--host MachineA` as parameters of mysqldump should work

Answer (score -1):

I put it like this and it works perfectly

mysqldump -P 7999 -h '192.168.1.25' -vv -u'user' -p'password' base_dados | gzip > base_dados.sql.gz

Comment: It would improve this immensely if you added in some explanation of how it addresses the original question.