# How can I move a MySQL database from 5.1 to 5.6?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.6

I have pretty big database, like with 5 000 000 rows in total. It is located in a remote server. I want to copy this database to my personal computer, for testing purposes. However I don't know the best option for this operation. Dumping the database does not look user friendly. Can I use Navicat's data transfer function to do this? Could it end with error? I think this operation can last few hours. Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

It's all [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html). What's wrong with

```
mysqldump options | mysql localhost_name -u me -pmy_password
```

(with valid options for your particular setup)? Check [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/taking-mysql-dump-from-another-machine) for a sample. I don't know for sure, but Navicat is, in all likelihood doing something similar in the background. [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html) is possibly better.